# While True break wont work when t >= 20000?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am making a program in python that finds the probability of getting a prime number (E) when n = any number from 0 - 200,000.  E = n^2+n+5.  However, the "while true, break" cycle doesn't work when t = 200,000.  Here is my code:

```
#import time
#Does E = n^2 + n + 5 always produce prime numbers?
n = 0
t = 0
p = 0
while 3 > 2:
  n2 = n*n
  E = n2 + n + 5
  n = n + 1 
  if E > 1:
    for i in range(2, E):
      if((E % i) == 0):
        print(E, "is not prime.")
        #time.sleep(3)
    else:
      print("Found a prime number!", E)
      #time.sleep(3)
      p = p + 1
  t = t + 1
  if(t >= 200000):
    break

fraction = p/t
percent_int = fraction*100
percent = int(percent_int)
print("The probability of getting a prime number is:", percent)
```

Comment: What specific behavior did you observe that makes you say the code doesn't work? "Doesn't work" is much more vague than you may have realized.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
  if(t >= 200000):
```

To:

```
  if(t > 200000):
```

Answer (score 0):

It just take to long because you run `for i in range(2, E):` inside while loop.

put `print(t)` inside while loop to observe progress of program to get idea how long it will take.

Answer (score 0):

Changing your code to this:

```
n = 0
t = 0
p = 0
while 3 > 2:
   n2 = n*n
   E = n2 + n + 5
   n = n + 1
   if E > 1:
      for i in range(2, E):
         if((E % i) == 0):
              pass
   else:
       print("Found a prime number!", E)
       p = p + 1
   t = t + 1
   print(t)
   if(t >= 200000):
       break

fraction = p/t
percent_int = fraction*100
percent = int(percent_int)
print("The probability of getting a prime number is:", percent)
```

and letting it run shows that `t` is only incremented every time a prime number is found.

You might want to break elsewhere, perhaps set t to 500